# MIDIUSB - Why is the command put twice?

Tags: programming, c, midi, struct

Consider this function:

```
void noteOn(uint8_t pitch) {
  midiEventPacket_t noteOn = {0x09, 0x90 | 9, pitch, 127};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(noteOn);
}
```

`midiEventPacket_t` is defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t header;
    uint8_t byte1;
    uint8_t byte2;
    uint8_t byte3;
}midiEventPacket_t;
```

The first nibble of the first byte of a MIDI message is the command: `0x90` ["note on"] and the second nibble is the MIDI channel: `9`, so what's sent over the wire should be `0x99` meaning "Note On, channel 9", with the two more bytes representing the pitch and the velocity.

My question is, why do all of the examples start with: `{0x09, 0x90 | 9,`? I'm not understanding the use of the struct here. Intuitively, I thought I would need: `{0x90 | 9, pitch, 127, 0}`. Why do all of the examples have that seemingly strange syntax?

## EDIT

After getting a great explanation below, here's my new function!

`void noteOn(uint8_t pitch) {
  midiEventPacket_t noteOnPacket;
  noteOnPacket.header = USB_CABLE_NUMBER | (MIDI_NOTE_ON >> 4);
  noteOnPacket.byte1 = MIDI_NOTE_ON | CHANNEL;
  noteOnPacket.byte2 = pitch;
  noteOnPacket.byte3 = MIDI_BUTTON_ON_VELOCITY;
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(noteOnPacket);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specs](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/midi10.pdf):

> The first byte in each 32-bit USB-MIDI Event Packet is a Packet Header contains a Cable Number (4 bits)
>   followed by a Code Index Number (4 bits). [...]
>
> [...]
>
> The Cable Number (CN) is a value ranging from 0x0 to 0xF indicating the number assignment of the
>   Embedded MIDI Jack associated with the endpoint that is transferring the data. The Code Index Number
>   (CIN) indicates the classification of the bytes in the MIDI_x fields. The following table summarizes these
>   classifications.
>
> CIN | MIDI_x Size | Description
>
> [...]
>
> 0x9 | 3 | Note-on
>
> [...]

No rationale is given *why* the CIN is required if the full message is also included, but it could be used for quicker routing of the event to the routine that will process it.

Comment: OH, LIGHTBULB moment. `midiEventPacket_t` represents the USB packet, not the MIDI packet